# How to use Alertify in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, alertifyjs

I'm relative new to Angular2 so be patient with me.

I tryed to use *Alertify.js* in my Angular2 project for a custom dialog box but i can't get Alertify running...
I'm not that familiar with js so i tryed to use alertify.js in Typescript or rather tryed to make a module out of that alertify.js file.

I found something about using  *.d.ts*  files and I also found the alertify.d.ts file on github but I cant figure out how to use it. I tryed several things but in the end I failed.

Is there anyone who can help me with this problem or can show me an alternative for a custom dialogbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to use Alertify as easy as possible for me.

I just bound it to my `index.html` with

`<script src="alertify/alertify.min.js"></script>`

and then just calling it `alertify.METHODE()`.

So making alertify global makes its very easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `tsd` or `typings` then the simplest way is to copy `alertify.d.ts` file to your source dir, include `alertify.js` using script tag and add next line to `main.ts`/`boot.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="../path-to/alertify.d.ts" />
```